# Weird Footnote Numbering in Table

Tags: tables, footnotes, xfootnote

I have a table with two `\footnotemark`. Right below the table I added two `\footnotetext`.

What happens now is that the first footnote in the table receives a 32 (correct), the second one a 34 (incorrect). 
In addition, at the end of the page, both footnotes are denoted as 34. A 32 and 33 are completely missing.

In the following image you can see the inconsistent numbering in the table:

[image: Table with weired numbering]

The Latex Code is given in the following:

```
\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\label{tab:large_biomed_statistics}
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
\begin{tabular}{|l|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\textbf{Ontology} &     \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}All \\     Classes\end{tabular}}} &     \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Small Overlap \\     NCI\end{tabular}}} &     \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Small Overlap \\     FMA\end{tabular}}} &     \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Small Overlap\\     SNOMED\end{tabular}}} \\ \hline
\textbf{NCI}      & 66,724                                                                                                           & -                                                                                                                          & 6,488                                                                                                                  & 23,958                                                                                                                       \\ \hline
\textbf{FMA}      & 78,989                                                                                                           & 3,696                                                                                                                      & -                                                                                                                      & 10,157                                                                                                                       \\ \hline
\textbf{SNOMED}   & 122,464\footnotemark 
& 51,128                                                                                                                 & 13,412                                                                                                                     & -                                                                                                                        \\ \hline
\end{tabular}%
}
\caption[OAEI Large BioMed Statistics]{OAEI Large BioMed Statistics: The     numbers refer to the number of classes in the corresponding ontology. They     are compiled from the downloadable material of the track\footnotemark.}
\end{table}

\footnotetext{{Note that for the SNOMED ontology this number does still not     represent the whole ontology but the subset with NCI and FMA. In the track,     however, the full ontology is not provided.}}%
\footnotetext{see \url{http://www.cs.ox.ac.uk/isg/projects/SEALS/oaei/2017.5/LargeBio_dataset_oaei2017.zip}}%
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Could you post a full, minimal code reproducing the problem?

Comment: Before you use `\footnotetext` you have to decrease the counter: `\addtocounter{footnote}{-1}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I played around with `\addtocounter{footnote}{-1}` as suggested by @Herbert (thank you).

**The solution**: 
After the first `\footnotemark`, the counter needs to be decreased, so I added `\addtocounter{footnote}{-1}`

Before the first `\footnotetext`, the counter needs to be decreased again `\addtocounter{footnote}{-1}`. After each `\footnotetext`, the counter needs to be increased by 1 (`\addtocounter{footnote}{1}`).

The resulting numbering (32, 33) fits into the text and is also correct at the end of the page.

Corrected Code:

```
\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\label{tab:large_biomed_statistics}
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
\begin{tabular}{|l|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\textbf{Ontology} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}All \\ Classes\end{tabular}}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Small Overlap \\ NCI\end{tabular}}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Small Overlap \\ FMA\end{tabular}}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Small Overlap\\ SNOMED\end{tabular}}} \\ \hline
\textbf{NCI}      & 66,724                                                                                                       & -                                                                                                                  & 6,488                                                                                                              & 23,958                                                                                                               \\ \hline
\textbf{FMA}      & 78,989                                                                                                       & 3,696                                                                                                              & -                                                                                                                  & 10,157                                                                                                               \\ \hline
\textbf{SNOMED}   & 122,464\footnotemark \addtocounter{footnote}{-1}
& 51,128                                                                                                             & 13,412                                                                                                             & -                                                                                                                    \\ \hline
\end{tabular}%
}
\caption[OAEI Large BioMed Statistics]{OAEI Large BioMed Statistics\\
The numbers refer to the number of classes in the corresponding ontology. They are compiled from the downloadable material of the track\footnotemark.}
\end{table}

\addtocounter{footnote}{-1}
\footnotetext{{Note that for the SNOMED ontology this number does still not represent the whole ontology but the subset with NCI and FMA. In the track, however, the full ontology is not provided.}}%
\addtocounter{footnote}{1}
\footnotetext{see \url{http://www.cs.ox.ac.uk/isg/projects/SEALS/oaei/2017.5/LargeBio_dataset_oaei2017.zip}}%
\addtocounter{footnote}{1}
```